# [The issue has been resolved]ASP.NET Core Web API Exception handling middleware unable to capture exceptions

Tags: c, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi

## [The issue has been resolved]

I am targeting ASP.NET Core Web API on .NET 8.0.

My issue is that my exception handling middleware is unable to capture exceptions,

When calling the interface, an error is directly reported, pointing to the code that initially threw the exception, stating that the exception was not handled, and then the program is forced to stop running,

Found the same problem online, but couldn't find a solution

#### Program.cs:

```
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Using custom exception handling middleware
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
```

#### ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.cs:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next ;
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> _logger ;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("An unhandled exception occurred：" + ex.Message);
        _logger.LogError(ex, "An unhandled exception occurred");
        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync("An unhandled exception occurred");
    }
}
```

#### TestController.cs

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            throw new Exception("this is a test exception message.");
        }
    }
```

## The issue has been resolved: I found through breakpoints that exceptions can be caught, but I overlooked that this is an issue where the debugger intercepts exceptions. The debugging version will be intercepted by the debugger when throwing exceptions, and the exception will only be thrown to the exception middleware after you press the "Continue" button

Comment: When you use your debugger, set a breakpoint on the first line of `ExceptionHandlingMiddleware.Invoke` and again on the `await HandleExceptionAsync` call-site - does it break on enter and on catch when the test exception is thrown?

Comment: You can check the following [article](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/how-i-have-handled-exception-globally-in-asp-net-core-api-7b8c2603af72)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use try {} catch {} inside your middleware. You could simply use the build-in exception feature `app.UseExceptionHandler(builder => builder.UseMiddleware<YourMiddleware>());` and inside the middleware you can access the thrown excpetion with this code

```
IExceptionHandlerPathFeature? exceptionFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
Exception? exception = exceptionFeature?.Error;
```